# Why isn't a loop forming when I call draw_petal(brad)?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to create a flower, but when I call `draw_petal(brad`) the loops aren't forming.

I do the following:

```
import turtle

def draw_petal(some_turtle):
    for i in range(1,3):
     some_turtle.forward(200)
     some_turtle.right(60)
     some_turtle.forward(200)
     some_turtle.right(120)


def draw_flower():
    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("yellow")

#create a turtle brad - draws a flower.

    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.shape("turtle")
    brad.color("black")
    brad.speed(2)

    for i in range(1,37):
       draw_petal(brad)
       brad.right(10)

       window.exitonclick()

draw_flower()
```

I want the turtle to turn 10 degrees right and form a loop 36 times.

Comment: Solved it. The problem was that window.exitonclick() is in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

> Solved it. The problem was that window.exitonclick() is in the for
>   loop.

It's great that you were able to solve your problem!  A typical layout for a turtle program like this is roughly:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def draw_petal(some_turtle):

    for _ in range(2):
        some_turtle.forward(200)
        some_turtle.right(60)
        some_turtle.forward(200)
        some_turtle.right(120)

def draw_flower():

    """ Create a turtle named brad; draw a flower. """

    brad = Turtle("turtle")
    brad.color("black")
    brad.speed('slow')

    for _ in range(36):
        draw_petal(brad)
        brad.right(10)

    brad.hideturtle()

window = Screen()
window.bgcolor("yellow")

draw_flower()

window.exitonclick()
```